# No wi-fi adapter found in Ubuntu 18.04, it was working properly before but stopped working yesterday, Intel Wireless 8260 adapter

Tags: networking, 18.04, dual-boot, wireless, iwlwifi

**QUESTION UPDATED**

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Wifi was working fine until two days ago, and it stopped working for no apparent reason. Wifi in Windows 10 is working fine.

There has been some developments in the question above and the problem itself changed. In my Asus Zenbook, I had originally disabled Secure Boot, but when this problem started to happen I realised that it was enabled again. As mentioned in the previous question the behaviour of Ubuntu recognising the card was quite erratic. However, there was in the BIOS an option called **Secure boot control** which was enabled. I don't know what it means, but I disabled it and the erratic behaviour disappeared.

Since then, the wifi adapter is still not working, but `lshw` always gives the following message:

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ef000000-ef001fff
```

Other commands:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0110]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.626468] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[    3.626772] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[    3.651088] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5

sudo rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo modinfo iwlwifi | grep 24F3 | grep 0050
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000050bc*sc*i*
```

I have the following kernel, updated yesterday (Ubuntu is 18.04.4):

```
uname -a
Linux arbexzen 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: "sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source" That's a driver for a Broadcom wireless device. It is not relevant at all for an Intel.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for that, I was trying everything

Comment: I would try: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`; reboot and see if there is any improvement. I am a bit skeptical, but please try it for completeness.

Comment: Dear @chili555, it did improve things - although not working yet. When I type ```sudo lshw -C network``` now I can see the Wireless 8260 network controller. I will update the question.

Comment: @chili555 actually things seem weird. After I restarted the laptop again, the wireless card disappeared once again and the updated commands above are all empty.

Comment: Is the behavior changed if you cold boot into Ubuntu vs. reboot from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: Dear @chili555, thanks for the reply. I tried rebooting it from Ubuntu to Ubuntu, from Windows to Ubuntu, switching off and on straight to Ubuntu a few times. I couldn't really see any pattern. Sometimes it shows nothing at all, sometimes it finds the card with lshw. Once it found by rfkill as will, but showed as DISABLED in lshw (but not blocked).

It makes me think it could be hardware related, but in Windows it always works.

Comment: I'm very puzzled that it sometimes appears on PCI bus 0000:02:00.0 and sometimes on bus 0000:00:1c.6 as seen in your dmesg above. Are there any clues here: `dmesg | grep 02:00` or else: `dmesg | grep 1c.6` As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Right now I'm a a restart where nothing appears. This is the output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BTBPSrCZm3/

Comment: I rebooted and this time lshw returned the adapter. This is the output of the above commands when this happens:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G7byS5MWCg/

Comment: @chili555 I changed the question text as the problem changed after I disabled "Secure boot control" in BIOS (prior only "Secure boot" was disabled).

Comment: Try to disable Fast start in Windows. It looks like that is the problem.

Comment: Hi @Pilot6, thanks! The option to disable fast start in Windows does not appear because hibernate is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it was a hardware issue.

I sent the laptop to the shop for a checkup and internal cleanup and they found that the wifi adapter connector was slightly off. Windows was still able to establish the connection, but Ubuntu wasn't. This also explains why sometimes the adapter was detected, but unclaimed, and why sometimes it wasn't detected at all.

So, for everyone experiencing similar problems, a wifi adapter working in Windows but not in Ubuntu may still be a hardware issue.