# can't find WIFI connection in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, wireless

I have Ubuntu 19.10 version, since I've installed it i can't connect to WIFI when I go to setting and WIFI I see the message "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". However to check if it's a hardware problem or system I check it in my Windows OS, and in Windows I can connect to WIFI without any difficulties.
I've searched in the web for tutorials to solve this problem, found many, but each one doesn't relate to this specific problem.

Some details about the laptop:
DELL Vostro 5490
Wireless: 802.11ac 1x1 WiFi and Bluetooth

I ran `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` command and receive the following output:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Please help me to solve this problem, BTW I don't have windows OS anymore.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: 00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: I asked you to [edit] your question, not to post the output as a comment.

Comment: I suggest to connect to the internet by another way and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-firmware`

Comment: Just tried that, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: The output is too long. Is any specific line that will help?

Comment: It shouldn't be very long. It is one command, not two.

Comment: it's more than 5000 characters. 
Can't add it to as a comment, and it make the post be messy. don't have permission to upload an image.

Comment: Can you edit your question with more information about your wifi adapter? like is it built into the motherboard, a pcie card, a usb dongle, etc.? Make and model?

Comment: It looks like you are running `dmesg` without `grep`. It can't be that long.

Comment: I asked a similar question a few days ago, no answer so far: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257107/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-in-ubuntu-18-04-it-was-working-properly-before-but-stopp?noredirect=1#comment2124830_1257107